# how do you change the color of the chrome browser's tabs with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image]

How do you color the individual tabs in the Chrome browser using javascript?

Is that even possible?

Comment: After doing a Google search, it doesn't seem like this is something Javascript is capable of. You might be able to change it if your browser has a setting for it, or if you get an extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This capability isn't even available to Chrome extensions.